# Does the cql python library support Cassandra v2?

Tags: python, cassandra

I am trying to use the cql python library with Cassandra 2.0.4.  I'm getting errors like:

```
drop table if exists mytable
Bad Request: line 1:14 mismatched input 'exists' expecting EOF

create table mytable ( ... rowNum bigint, primary key (rowNum))
Bad Request: line 1:159 extraneous input ')' expecting EOF

create table mytable ( timestamp timestamp, ...)
Bad Request: line 1:94 no viable alternative at input 'timestamp'
```

Is the cql library not supposed to work with Cassandra 2.0.4?  I started by using the cassandra library, which does work with these cases, but the BATCH command does not seem to be supported in that interface, while it is in cql.

It's hard for me to tell which of the many python Cassandra interfaces I should be using with version 2...

Thanks!

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

*Update*: As of May.29th, 2014, a new version of the [Cassandra Python driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver) was released (see [notes here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datastax-python-driver-2-0-released)). This version works with both Apache Cassandra 1.2 and 2.0.

The [python-driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver) will be able to connect to a C* 2.0 cluster, but none of the new features in C* 2.0 will be available. If you need a quick reference for the new features in C* 2.0, I'd say this [PDF summarizes](http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/WP-DataStax-WhatsNewC2.0.pdf) them well.

Anyways, after the 1.0 of the driver will be released, work on C* 2.0 new features will start so (hopefully) it won't be long until these new features will show up in the driver.

Right now I'm not aware of any other Python driver that supports the CQL spec coming with C* 2.0